# Ordered sequences of edges such that vertices appear an even number of times

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Given an undirected graph with an edge set $E$, and where an edge is an unordered pair of vertices, how many ordered sequences of size $L$ of edges from $E$ exist such that all the vertices that are present in a sequence appear an even number of times?

For example $\{(x,y),(z,w),(x,y),(z,w)\}$ is a sequence of size $L=4$. The edges participating in the sequence are $(x,y)$ and $(z,w)$ and each of the vertices $x,y,z,w$ appears exactly twice.

I am particularly interested in edge sets of planar graphs (e.g., two-dimensional square or triangular lattices).

Comment: Denote by $P(L)$ the number of ordered sequences of size $L$ of edges from $E(G)$. And let the graph $G$ have no loops. We have $P(1)=0$, $P(2)=|E(G)|$, $P(3)$ is the number of triangles in $G$.

Comment: And here's another one.

Call a pair of edges $(x,y),(u,v)$ an independent pair if $|\{x,y,u,v\}|=4$. We have $P(4)=|E(G)|+I+S$, where $I$ is the number of independent pairs of $G$, $S$ is the number of squares of $G$.